# How do I start service on Reboot?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, bootcompleted

I am trying to automatically start an Android service when the device reboots.  I have tried to accomplish this using Receive_Boot_Complete permission, BroadcastReceiver with Boot_Complete intent action with no success.  I'm very well aware that after Android 3.0 apps are placed in a stopped state on reboot and therefore no receivers are able to run.  However, there are several mobile security apps such as [Lookout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lookout) that are run services and processes on reboot.  How are they able to accomplish this?

```
<!-- Listen for the device starting up -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.tpss.beacon.BootCompleteReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>     


  public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    context.startService(new Intent(context, UpdateGeofenceService.class));  
   }
}
```

Comment: Post your code. You're doing something wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

When the system boots, it sends a broadcast of BOOT_COMPLETED intent. So, you have to create a BroadcastReceiver to catch that intent:

```
public class BReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "onReveive BOOT_COMPLETED");

            // start your service
            context.startService(new Intent("your_service"));
    }
}
```

Then you modify the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".BReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Don't forget to add the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Your suggestion is the approach I am currently using but haven't been able to get to work.